# Dotnet EF with external PostGres fails in migrate because db is not ready

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

i have a Webapplication in C# which connects to a PostGres Database using Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL. When running locally, i start up the database and then the App and it works fine. However, when it gets deployed, it runs in a docker-compose setup, and since the app starts faster than the Postgres, it crashes with "Connection Refused" or "the database system is starting up".

My Migrate looks something like this:

```
        public void Migrate()
    {
        var pendingMigrations = _context.Database.GetPendingMigrations().Count();
        if (pendingMigrations > 0)
        {
            Logger.LogInformation($"Applying {pendingMigrations} migration(s)");
            _context.Database.Migrate();
            _context.SaveChanges();
            Logger.LogDebug($"Database migration complete");
        }
        else
        {
            Logger.LogDebug($"No pending migrations");
        }
    }
```

And my startup.cs like this:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContextPool<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(MyDbContextFactory.PostgresConnectionString));
        services.AddScoped<IMyDb, MyDb>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IMyDb db)
    {
        ...
        db.Migrate();
    }
```

What would be best practice to ensure it waits for the Database to start up? I think i somewhere saw something like running the Migrate() call in a loop and catching the exception?